# I want to move the value from Cell B to Cell C if Cell A values is changed

Tags: excel, vba

I have values in Column A and B.
Column A value should be Pass/Fail.
If Column A value is changed from Fail to Pass then Column B value should move to Column C.

I mean to say if value is changed from A to B then B should move to another cell.

E.g:

Before Change:

```
Column A   Column B  Column C 

 Fail         123       -

 Pass          -        456
```

After Change:

```
Column A   Column B  Column C 

 Pass        -          123

 Fail        456         -
```

Once the values is changed it should happen automatically. i dont want to run this macro every time.

Thanks in Adavance!

Comment: Your example suggests that you also want changing Pass to Fail to move the item back to column B? However, have you attempted any code yourself? In which, case you should show your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
CR = Target.Address
SplitCR = Split(CR, "$")
CC = SplitCR(1)
CR = SplitCR(2)
If CC = "A" Then
    CellBValue = Range("B" & CR)
    CellCValue = Range("C" & CR)
    Range("B" & CR).Value = CellCValue
    Range("C" & CR).Value = CellBValue
End If
End Sub
```

Paste the above code in your sheet.

Comment: +1 short and sweet. The limitation is that if OP had Fail in cell $A$1 and the OP just changed the same cell to Fail (retyped it), the code will swap B and C and the result will be an unintented swap. The code will work very well if OP was changing from Fail to Pass and Pass to Fail

Comment: You are right. I wrote the code without considering specific value in column A. I hope the person who asked the question can manipulate the code to suit his needs.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to put this in Sheet1's VBA code

```
' Requirement: Let's say the data before change looks like this:
' Column A -- Column B -- Column C
' Fail           123          -
' Pass            -          456
'
' After change of column A, data should look like this:
' Column A -- Column B -- Column C
' Pass            -          123
' Fail           456          -
'
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Do calculations only if the target of change is 1st column (i.e. column A)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then

        ' Let's remember the data that's already in Column B and Column C
        Dim DataInColumnB, DataInColumnC As String
        DataInColumnB = Range(Replace(Target.Address, "A", "B")).Value
        DataInColumnC = Range(Replace(Target.Address, "A", "C")).Value

        ' We assume that if A has Pass, dash will be in column B
        ' and if A has Fail, dash will be in column C
        ' If we find that A has Pass but B is not a dash, we must swap information in B and C
        ' Similarly if A has Fail but C is not a dash, we must also swap information in B and C
        If (LCase(Target) = "pass" And DataInColumnB <> "-") Or _
        (LCase(Target) = "fail" And DataInColumnC <> "-") Then

            Range(Replace(Target.Address, "A", "B")).Value = DataInColumnC
            Range(Replace(Target.Address, "A", "C")).Value = DataInColumnB

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```